# Convert JSON nodes as columns to be selected

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

Please refer to this scenario:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Status VARCHAR(100), List VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @Table (Status, List) 
VALUES ('Active', '[{"Header":"H1","Detail":"D1"}]')

SELECT * 
FROM @Table
```

This returns the output

```
ID          Status             List    
------------------------------------------------                                                                                         
1           Active    [{"Header":"H1","Detail":"D1"}]
```

Is there a way to extract the JSON nodes as columns in order to get the below output

```
ID          Status             Header        Detail
------------------------------------------------------                                                                                       
1           Active             H1              D1
```

Comment: Try with this https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/importing-json-collections-sql-server/

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Sql Server 2016

Comment: Does the json value always contain the same columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try with additional `APPLY` operator and `OPENJSON` with explicit schema definition:

Table:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,Status VARCHAR(100),List VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Table(Status,List) VALUES ('Active','[{"Header":"H1","Detail":"D1"}]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Status, j.Header, j.Detail
FROM @Table t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(List) WITH (
   Header nvarchar(2) '$.Header',
   Detail nvarchar(2) '$.Detail'
) j
```

Output:

```
ID  Status  Header  Detail
1   Active  H1      D1
```

Comment: Assuming the json has a fixed schema, that would be the correct answer.